# Specific website not opening on one whole network

Tags: networking, website

Our college website is not opening while using college network, however, the website works perfectly on any outside networks.
The website is hosted by a provider, not college.
I've tried restarting the main router, pinging and checking the connection with website with WinMTR.
The browser gets the "too long to respond" error.
No settings have been changed anywhere, what could possibly be the issue?

These are WinMTR readings:

```
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|                         192.168.243.254 -    0 |   14 |   14 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                         193.219.187.145 -    0 |   14 |   14 |    0 |    1 |   18 |    0 |
|                           193.219.153.5 -    0 |   14 |   14 |    3 |    4 |   20 |    3 |
|                          193.219.153.26 -    0 |   14 |   14 |    4 |    4 |    5 |    5 |
|                     RACKRAY.balt-ix.net -    0 |   14 |   14 |    4 |    7 |   25 |    5 |
|           n11-b16-lt1.node.serveriai.lt -    0 |   14 |   14 |    5 |    6 |   21 |    5 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
```

Comment: What is the website's address? Do you have root access to the web server?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER FOUND.

The ip's were blocked because firewall on server's side registered 282 failed logins on server e-mail system.